# Content/Character Encoding - Why Does HTTP Header(Content-Type) Take Precedence Over Meta Tags(Http-Equiv)?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, http-headers, meta-tags

I have been studying content encoding for some time now, but I'm still learning.

My understanding is, the content/character encoding decides how a web browser renders characters outside of the normal ASCII range (0-127). Basically, there are different standard for interpreting those characters and if the right content encoding is specified, then they interpret correctly. If the wrong character encoding is specified, you may end up displaying characters that don't make sense.

One thing that I found quite surprising is that if the HTTP header Content-Type field and the meta tag http-equiv mention a different encoding, the browser should override the http-equiv meta tag with the HTTP header.

It seems to me that the person producing the HTML document would be most likely to know the correct content encoding, as it's their content. If they use a tool to create the HTML, it's easy for that tool to automatically include the meta tag. The server, on the other hand, might serve content with many different encoding formats or have a default that's different. Most people producing a HTML document would have control over the meta tag, but they may or may not be able to control the server headers, and the level of technical skill required to do that is higher in many cases.

Content can also be saved locally as .htm or .html, or copied from one server to another. However, the HTTP header information is generally not retained. Thus, if the information is copied, the meta tag would generally go with it. There's a very easy chance that data copied from one server would go to another server and be served with the wrong encoding. It's easy to make a file that loads on the web but fails to load properly if saved locally.

I can't seem to find or think of any reason to use the HTTP header, other than as a backup or initial guess of the encoding.

I'm quite interested and curious on the reasoning behind this decision. It seems to me that it makes more logical sense to let the meta tag take precedence, as it seems like it would be a more reliable indication of the true encoding. Does anyone know the history on this decision and how it was made?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this from my own experience and since I haven't seen anyone else reply to you, I thought I'd share my perspective on it.

I think the reason why the server's encoding gets to override the webpage's encoding is because historically the server would convert any text-based files you upload into a format suitable for the server. This includes rewriting the endianess. This is as opposed to binary files which didn't get converted.

Because the server converted the text-based file, it would know what the encoding was, because that was what it encoded it into.

When it subsequently serves the text file as a webpage, it has to override the original encoding because it was potentially changed.